# Django - Raw query to ORM

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    emp_no = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hire_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'employees'


class Salaries(models.Model):
    emp_no = models.ForeignKey(Employees, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='emp_no',related_name='salaries', primary_key=True)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'salaries'
        unique_together = (('emp_no', 'from_date'),)
```

Mysql raw query:

```
SELECT `employees`.`emp_no`, `employees`.`birth_date`, `employees`.`first_name`, `employees`.`last_name`, `employees`.`gender`, `employees`.`hire_date`,
    (
         SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'salary', `salaries`.`salary`,
                'from_date', `salaries`.`from_date`,
                'to_date', `salaries`.`to_date`
            )
         ) FROM `salaries` WHERE (`employees`.`emp_no` = `salaries`.`emp_no`)
    ) as salaries
     FROM `employees`
     INNER JOIN `salaries` root_salaries ON `root_salaries`.`salary` > 60000
     WHERE `employees`.`emp_no` = `root_salaries`.`emp_no` LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

Output for raw query:

```
[
            {
                "emp_no": 10017,
                "birth_date": "1958-07-06",
                "first_name": "Cristinel",
                "last_name": "Bouloucos",
                "gender": "F",
                "hire_date": "1993-08-03",
                "salaries": [
                    {
                        "salary": 71380,
                        "to_date": "1994-08-03",
                        "from_date": "1993-08-03"
                    },
                    {
                        "salary": 75538,
                        "to_date": "1995-08-03",
                        "from_date": "1994-08-03"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "emp_no": 10018,
                "birth_date": "1954-06-19",
                "first_name": "Kazuhide",
                "last_name": "Peha",
                "gender": "F",
                "hire_date": "1987-04-03",
                "salaries": [
                    {
                        "salary": 55881,
                        "to_date": "1988-04-02",
                        "from_date": "1987-04-03"
                    },
                    {
                        "salary": 59206,
                        "to_date": "1989-04-02",
                        "from_date": "1988-04-02"
                    },
                    {
                        "salary": 61361,
                        "to_date": "1990-04-02",
                        "from_date": "1989-04-02"
                    }
                ]
            }
         ]
```

**My question is how to generate the above raw query using Django ORM.**
Thanks.

Comment: If you have SQL for the query needed, by far the fastest way is to call SQLAlchemy connection with the raw SQL. If you want an ORM way of doing it, please show us what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: Actually i know only raw queries. i want to know about how to achieve this output using models and serializers.

Comment: You don't need SQLAlchemy for that, you can use Django's connection for raw queries.  @Gnudiff

Comment: As for the actual question - what exactly are you struggling with? What did you try, what didn't you understand? Don't expect folks to just give you a solution - show us the effort you've made before asking

Comment: Actual question is how to make above raw query in django orm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views.py

```
query_set = Employees.objects.filter(salaries__salary__gt=60000).annotate(
        salaries_1=Subquery(
            Salaries.objects.filter(emp_no=OuterRef('emp_no'), salary__gt=60000).values(
                salaries=JSONArrayAgg(JSONObject(
                    salary=F('salary'),
                    from_date=F('from_date'),
                    to_date=F('to_date')
                ))))
    ).distinct()[100:200]

    employee_ser = EmployeesWithSalaryGroupSerializer(query_set, many=True)
    data = employee_ser.data
```

Serializers.py

```
class EmployeesWithSalaryGroupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    emp_no = serializers.IntegerField()
    birth_date = serializers.DateField()
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    gender = serializers.CharField()
    hire_date = serializers.DateField()
    salaries_1 = serializers.JSONField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super(EmployeesWithSalaryGroupSerializer, self).to_representation(instance=instance)
        ret['salaries'] = json.loads(instance.salaries_1)
        ret.pop('salaries_1')
        return ret
```